# VUE: динамический import компонента из $route.params

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Товарищи vue spa строители! Столкнулся с проблемой следующего содержания: мне необходимо динамически подгружать на страницу компонент имя которого передается в компонент родитель из роута. Если более подробно:

```
<component v-bind:is="'currentStory'"></component>

components: {
  'currentStory': () => {
    return import(`@/components/stories/dnevnik.vue`)
  }
}
```

Вот так это работает. Но вместо dnevnik.vue мне необходимо определять что-то вроде `@/components/stories/${this.$route.params.story}.vue`

Но проблема в том, что в контексте components this - равен undefined.
Проще говоря, как мне осуществить импорт компонента, имя которого лежит в $route.params.story?

Comment: А судя по [доке](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) всё должно работать...

Comment: Мой пример, описанный в вопросе, работает. Я не знаю как мне определять имя компонента из параметра роута.

Answer (score 1):

Удивительное совпадение, но именно сегодня пришлось столкнуться с той же проблемой. Удалось найти решение [здесь](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamic-components-with-dynamic-imports/20703/8?u=smellyshovel).

Если коротко, то советуют не динамически импортировать компонент в секции `components`, а вместо этого биндить атрибут `is` к вычисляемому свойству (`computed`), которое возвращает динамически-импортированный компонент.

Решение 100% рабочее, проверил локально, но, как мне кажется, недостаточно надежное для использования в продакшн. Уверен, могут всплыть какие-то баги.

```
<template>
    <component v-bind:is="'currentStory'"></component>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    computed: {
        currentStory() {
            return () => import(`@/components/stories/${ this.$route.params.story }.vue`);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```